# How to fix position of buttons in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have two `buttons` that change position depending on the `<h4>` tag that appears/disappears using JS depending on the events on the page. How can I make the buttons stay in the position they are when `h4` is visible? (lower than when not visible).

Inline css is just for testing.

Thank you!

```
  <h4 id="greutate">Greutate: <span id="greu">20</span> kg</h4>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-right: 2%;">Inapoi Acasa</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 2%;">Cumpara Folie</button>
```

Comment: Funky smelling idea - instead of hiding the h4 change the colour of its text to the background colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `position:absolute` css property to position any element relative to a `position:relative` parent, which would be a wrapper around the `h4` and `button` elements you have described. That way, the h4's visibility will not affect the position of the buttons.

You may also use `opacity:0` to hide the h4 tag, which will leave it in the same position and also not move the buttons.

Comment: Can I also use the opacity trick on a `<select>` tag? EDIT: Yes, I can. Just tested it rn

Comment: @VladutMaican You can use the `opacity` property on any visible element as far as I'm aware. However, that will not change its mouse events behaviors, so this is only useful if you won't be placing anything else over the hidden element (except in very simple cases without any mouse events for either elements).

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle opacity, but screenreaders would still read the heading. If you're concerned about accessibility, use `absolute` positioning on the elements, and wrap in a container with a fixed height:

```js
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('greutate');
    var current = el.style.display;

    el.style.display = current === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.container .btn-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

#greutate {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
<h4 id="greutate">Greutate: <span id="greu">20</span> kg</h4>
  <div class="btn-container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-right: 2%;">Inapoi Acasa</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 2%;">Cumpara Folie</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button style="margin-top: 5%;" id="toggle">Toggle</button>
```